# Scrapy: ImportError: No module named pipelines

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm having issues getting my scraper to load an item pipeline. In my attempts to try and add my custom pipeline I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named pipelines
```

I've tried the documentation but it doesn't really explain how to set the `ITEM_PIPELINE` option path. This is the example from the docs:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.PricePipeline': 300,
    'myproject.pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline': 800,
}
```

Where does `myproject` come from?

Below is the directory structure of my application:

```
├── README.md
├── bot.py
├── data
│   └── formax.json
├── pipelines
│   ├── FormaxPipeline.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── praw.ini
├── requirements.txt
└── scrapers
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── formax.py
```

In the `formax.py` class I set some settings.

```
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'pipelines.FormaxPipeline': 100
    },
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
}
```

I run like so from the root directory:

```
scrapy runspider scrapers/formax.py -o data/formax.json
```

The scraper fails with the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named pipelines
```

How can I add the custom pipelines to settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things. First, Scrapy expects here that you have standard Scrapy [project structure](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project) where `myproject` is your project name (and name of that project's folder).

Second, `ITEM_PIPELINES` needs you to specify classes of your pipelines, from what I can see (structure of your application and your `custom_settings`) you specified just module. Instead of `pipelines.FormaxPipeline` you should have `pipelines.FormaxPipeline.FormaxPipeline` in the `ITEM_PIPELINES` settings. (Here I assume your class is named `FormaxPipeline` and is defined in `FormaxPipeline.py` file.)

But the actual error comes from the fact that Scrapy can't locate the module. Don't know exactly how to solve it more cleanly, because you already do something Scrapy doesn't expect (not having project structure), but one workaround is to run the spider this way:

```
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:." scrapy runspider scrapers/formax.py -o data/formax.json
```

i.e. to tell Python where to look for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the exact same problem and it was killing me for hours! I had the custom_settings variable set in my spider class and I had a pipeline class defined in the pipeline.py file which was a few folders up. Then, like you, I did something to the effect of: "myprojname.pipelines.CsvPipeline" and variations on it. Each time I got the module error.

Then I realized something. In the documentation, they're probably assuming that you're setting it in the settings.py file and not in the custom_settings variable inside the spider class (I see you haven't included the settings file here, but it comes with the scrapy startproject command, I'm sure). So, instead I made a file named pipelines.py in the SAME folder as my spider file was in. And then I just did "pipelines.CsvPipeline" and it worked!

So, I also tried just setting it in the general settings. Here I got no complaints when running my spider, but it also seemed like it didn't make use of it. So that wasn't an option for me.